# Salesforce connection timeout when sending attachments via 3rd party integration platform

Tags: api, integration, timeout

I'm trying to create attachments in Salesforce using a 3rd party integration platform (Boomi). The Boomi timeout has been increased to 10 minutes, but the Salesforce connection times out after 2 minutes; SFDC support says that the connection time can not be increased. It works when using Bulk API, but to avoid limits, I'm trying SOAP web service. No debug logs are created when I call SFDC's API.